# Why is the transaction log file not truncated though its simple recovery model?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, logs

My database is simple recovery model and when I view the free space in log file it shows 99%. Why doesn't my log file truncate the committed data automatically to free space in ldf file? When I shrink it does shrink. Please advice. I saw this question, [Why Does the Transaction Log Keep Growing or Run Out of Space?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space). But unlike that scenario I have a simple recovery model and my transactions seemed to have committed as there are no on going transactions and shirkable size is shown as 99%

Comment: @Kin This question is not a duplicate of that because here I have simple recovery model as the recover type yet it grows. This is a different scenario

Comment: Even though you are using simple recovery I would still consider this a duplicate question.

Comment: @ShawnMelton that other question doesn't provide an explanation on instances where the log would grow though the recovery mode is set to simple.

Comment: The duplicate Q & A does cover this question. Check `log_reuse_wait` for example. Perform a checkpoint if necessary and so on. All the details are in the target as far as I can tell.